# Why PhoneGap app starts with a delay? Is there any way to avoid it?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing an android app using phonegap. This app consists of location service, google account integration, google play service ,cordova plugins, custom plugins etc. The native version app starts without any delay and runs smoothly. But when I developed this same app on PhoneGap, it seemed to me slower than the native one. Even this app starts with a delay of 10 seconds.
I have also tested some other apps developed on Phonegap. Those also have the same problem. Is this a common problem of PhoneGap? Is there any way to recover this delay issue? If so, please put your valuable response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap doesn't take that long to start up, unless you have set a splash screen to show for 10sec :p. Personally I would profile any (blocking) JavaScript that runs upon initial page load. Performance of the Android JavaScript engine is very poor until recently.

Answer (score 1):

It may be loading something API-related, or something extra Phonegap puts in - unless your phone is a little bit older/slower than the average these days? Personally I use Eclipse/Android SDK, so maybe take a look at them too.

Comment: No one could develop any android app without Android SDK. I have tested apps on Galaxy Note series. So I don't think this is API version issue.